# Facebook Logout link is not getting located using Selenium webdriver

Tags: facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver

After User Menu gets opened,I am trying to locate 'Logout' link.It is not locating with partial link text answers available here.

I tried to locate it with class name , but no success.

[Facebook Logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPq44.png)

I have also tried with Relative xpath but its not working.

```
//li[@class='_54ni navSubmenu _6398 _64kz __MenuItem']//a[@class='_54nc']//span//span[@class='_54nh']
```

Please comment below if anyone got success in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this Xpath

```
//a[contains(@data-gt, 'menu_logout')]
```

Comment: I tried with this Xpath ,got below error:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(@data-gt, 'logout_menu_click')]ss='_54nh'] because of the following error:
``SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(@data-gt, 'logout_menu_click')]ss='_54nh']' is not a valid XPath expression.``

Comment: try remove `ss='_54nh']` it not part of the xpath and make sure you have wait after clicking the Menu

Comment: ``driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-gt, 'logout_menu_click')]")).click();``
Now, it is not giving any error but it is just closing the menu at the end of the script execution instead of logout.
I am using ``Thread.sleep(5000)`` to wait once Menu is opened.
@ewwink

Comment: There is no error now .But it is closing Menu instead of Logout, Please check my above comment.

Comment: I have not reload reload the page and not see that. edited the answer, previous xpath return multiple elements and correct Xpath is  `//a[contains(@data-gt, 'menu_logout')]`